# Display Alert if Checkbox is unchecked and text field is not empty

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I have this form when information is being store into DB. I have a checkbox and a text field. Either one are required, but if the text field isn't empty, there's a good chance the checkbox should be checked. So I'd like to display an Alert if the Text Field has a value in it, and the checkbox isn't checked. I'd like this alert to appear when hitting the Submit button. Here's my form:

```html
<form id="form" name="form" action=?post=yes" method "post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="close" id="close" value="Yes"><label for="close" title="Close this RMA">Close this RMA</label>
   <label><input type="text" name="dateshipped" id="dateshipped"/></label>
   <button type="submit">Save and Continue</button>
</form>
```

So if checkbox "close" IS NOT checked AND "dateshipped" IS NOT NULL, then display alert when click Submit.

Thank you.

Comment: are you open to jquery? and what have you tried?

Comment: And where did you get stuck when you attempted to solve this problem?

Comment: yes, jquery would be great. I tried this this: 

$('#submit').click(function () {
    if (!$('#close').is(':checked')) {
        alert('not checked');
        return false;
    }
});

This doesn't work and I need to check if "dateshipped" is empty as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can do a javascript function to be called on the onclick event in the submit button , like this

```
<button type="submit" onclick="callAfunction();">Save and Continue</button>
```

and define the function

```
callAfunction()
{

 //do the checks with:  document.getElementById('close').value 
  // display an alert("a message"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
onsubmit="return validate();" // add to your form tag

function validate() {
    checkbox = document.getElementById('myCheckbox').value;
    if (!checkbox) {
        alert('checkbox is empty');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

Button for submitting. It runs validateSubmit. It only submits if the function is true.

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onsubmit="return validateSubmit();" />
```

Here's the validate function. It gets the value of the checkbox and the text. If they're both falsy then it sets valid to a confirm box. The confirm box allows the user to select ok or cancel and returns true or false based on that.

```
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkboxID').value;
    var text = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
    if(!(checkbox || text))
        valid = confirm("Checkbox and text are empty. \n Continue?");
    return valid;
}
```

The condition could be written as (!checkbox && !text), however I find it simpler to read to only use one ! if I can. The rule is called [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) if you're interested.

If you're using jQuery, things become easier.

```
var checkbox = $('#checkboxID').prop( "checked" );
var text =$('#textBox').val();
```

Plus you can attach even handlers like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', validate);
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That's what I need to accomplish but it doesn't work for me. You can see my test here: http://rmasupport.prostatcorp.com/rma/test-check.html. Also, the condition should be "If the checkbox isn't checked AND the text field IS NOT empty, then alert with OK or CANCEL. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, for some reasons, I can't make it work. Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8x488smq/1/

Comment: Here's the edited fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/42bkcnL2/ I apologize for the confusion. I usually use jQuery,  and I neglected to test the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**    Following code working for me, At first you need to add a onclick="functionName();" then do the following code**

```
function myCkFunction() {
```

var checkBox = document.getElementById("close");

if (checkBox.checked == true){

```
alert('checked');
```

} else {

alert('Unchecked');

}
}